# How to check neo4j is running or not from php?

Tags: neo4j, zend-framework2, neoxygen

I want to send an email when my db is down. I don't know how to check neo4j is running or not from php. I am using neoxygen neoclient library to connect to neo4j. Is there any way around to do this ? I am using neo4j 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

As neo4j is operated by HTTP REST interface, you just need to check if the appropriate host is reachable:

```
if (@fopen("http://localhost:7474/db/data/","r")) {
    // database is up
}
```

(assuming it's running on localhost)

Answer (score 0):

a) Upgrade to graphaware neo4j-php-client, neoxygen is deprecated since months and has been ported there since more than a year.

b) You can just do a try/catch on a query :

```
try {
  $result = $client->run('RETURN 1 AS x');
  if (1 === $result->firstRecord()->get('x') { // db is running // }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
  // db is not running or connection cannot be made
}
```

Comment: christophe-willemsen Can I check it without run a query ?

Comment: The only way is to try to connect to the neo4j server. So or you make a simple http request to it manually or you issue a query